# Show that $X \cup \mathcal{E}(X)$ ( $X$ and the ends of $X$) is a compact Hausdorff space.

Tags: general-topology

Let  $X$ be a connected,locally connected, locally compact and Hausdorff space. Let $\mathcal{K}$ the family of compact subsets of $X$.

An end , $\epsilon$ is a function: $\mathcal{K} \rightarrow X$ mapping a compact $C$ to a connected component of $X-C$. Moreover if, $C_1 \subset C_2$ then $\epsilon(C_2) \subset \epsilon(C_1)$

Let $\mathcal{E}(X)$ denote the set of all ends of $X$. We can define a topology in $X \cup \mathcal{E}(X)$ with these neighborhoods:

$N_C(\epsilon_0)=\epsilon_0(C) \cup \{ \epsilon \in \mathcal{E}(X)$ $|\ $ $\epsilon(C)=\epsilon_0(C)\}$. $\forall C \in \mathcal{K}$

We want to show that $X \cup \mathcal{E}(X)$  is a compact and Hausdorff space.

If we suppose an open cover of $X \cup \mathcal{E}(X)$ and then pick one  $N_{C_0}(\epsilon_0)$ it's clear that $X-C$ will have at most n connected components. So every end must map $C$ to one of these connected components. Thus there are $n$ equivalence classes which depends on $C$. I mean $\epsilon_1 \sim \epsilon_2 \iff \epsilon_1(C)=\epsilon_2(C)$

From here i don't know how to continue because if I want to get the rest of ends i need to pick another neighborhood $N_{C_i}(\epsilon_i)$ but i can't work out a relation between $C_i$ and $C_0$.

$X \cup \mathcal{E}(X)$ in all the particular cases i've seen looks like a compactification of X but i don't know if this will help.

Comment: I am guessing that by _end_, you mean something like what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)) talks about. If so, it might be helpful to add a brief description of this concept to your question. It would also help if you state where this question comes from.

Comment: Can you clarify the definition of end, or at least give a reference? Can you confirm or deny the guess by Arthur Fischer, that it is what Wikipedia talks about? As written, I find it hard to tell what an end is.

Comment: I edited my post with a definition of end. If you could tell me whats not clear ill change it.

Comment: Unclarities in the definition: - where are the quantifiers in the definition of end?  Is an end a function from $X$ to $X$ that maps every compact $C$ to a connected component of $X-C$, or is it a function from some compact subset $C$ of $X$ to $X-C$? I suspect $C_1$ and $C_2$ range over all compact subsets of $C$ (or $X$, depending on the answer to the above question); do they? I also suspect an end is continuous, but is it? I guess you want $\cal E$ to be the set of all ends;is it? You def. of the topology has messed up MathJax; can you fix it? What is the relation with the end of Wikipedia?

Comment: @Magdiragdag: Let $\mathscr{K}$ be the family of compact subsets of $X$. An end $\epsilon\in\mathscr{E}(X)$ is an inclusion reversing function $\epsilon:\mathscr{K}\to\wp(X)$ such that $\epsilon(C)$ is a connected component of $X\setminus C$ for each $C\in\mathscr{K}$. I believe that the definition of nbhd of $\epsilon_0$ is supposed to read $$N_C(\epsilon_0)=\epsilon_0(C)\cup \{\epsilon\in\mathscr{E}(X):\epsilon(C)=\epsilon_0(C)\}\;,$$ where $C\in\mathscr{K}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  Thanks. It seems I was totally on the wrong track with the definition of end. I must admit I started to suspect that, looking more carefully at the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @Magdiragdag: You’re welcome. It may help to think about the subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ consisting of the union of the coordinate axes: it has four ends, one corresponding to each arm of the cross, and the topology described is the natural $4$-point compactification.

Comment: Hi. I've just edited the post properly. I apologize for such a messy and unclear post. I was in a hurry and i decided to post  the question without proper definitions which was clearly a bad decision. This exercise comes from Spivak's book on differential geometry vol I chapter 1. 

Thanks for you patience .